# How test value of a command with `\ifthenelse` and `\equal`?

Tags: conditionals, syntax, ifthenelse, xifthen

**Revised question**

(Trying to follow suggestion in comment by David Carlisle.)

I want to assign a string as the value of a command and then take alternative actions (by means of `ifthenelse`) according to whether the value of that string equals a particular value.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \newcommand{\thing}{whatever}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thing}{\string whatever}}{%
  {\newcommand{\result}{thing is `whatever'.}}
  {\newcommand{\result}{thing is something else.}}%
}

\begin{document}

\result

\end{document}
```

What is wrong there with my `\ifthenelse{\equal{\thing...` test there? The command `\result` is never given a value, for a latex run gives error:

```
./whatever.tex:13: Undefined control sequence.
l.13     \result
```

**Underlying purpose**

In the actual project, which is book-length and involves a preamble consisting of some dozen "helper" files that are input in the root document, several "style" commands such as `\thing` are defined in root document in order to allow choosing among alternatives for each of various aspects of the overall document design, e.g., text width, font families, header styles. In those "helper" files, `\ifthenelse` tests are used for each such "style" command (instead of the simple-minded definition of `\result` shown in my MWE).

Thus I will be able to change such style parameters just by changing a word in the root document preamble, without having to burrow into the individual "helper" files and make edits there.

**Original question**

Using the generic TeX package `texapi`— or otherwise — (along with `ifthen`) I want to "declare" a string name, assign a string value to that name, and then take some action conditional upon that value.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{texapi.tex}
\newstring{thing}
% HOW assign a value here to the string `thing'?

\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{thing}{\string whatever}}{%
  {\newcommand{\result}{``It's whatever.''}}
  {\newcommand{\result}{``It's something else.''}}%
}

\begin{document}

\result

\end{document}
```

Is this possible and, if so, how?

(The packages I've looked at, namely, `xstring` and `stringstring`, give lots of commands for manipulating and testing strings, but do not seem to have commands to assign a string value.)

Comment: `\newstring{thing}` defines `thing` as the string, to be used in comparisons such as `\ifprefix`, `\ifsuffix` or `\ifcontains`. Definitely not to be used with `\ifthenelse` and you *can't* assign it a value.

Comment: It would be nice to know (with some pseudocode) what you're after.

Comment: can you not simply use `\newcommand\thing{whatever}`  to be tested via `\ifthenelse{\thing}{whatever}....` ?

Comment: You have been become very familiar with Ti*k*Z, so why don't you just use `pgfkeys` for that? They allow you to do all sort of things, of course also to implement switches. One way is to say `blabla/.code={\blablatrue}`, of course you need to introduce `\newif\ifblabla` before. Then you can say `\ifblabla\typeout{true}\else\typeout{false}\fi`, where you can replace the typepouts with more meaningful commands.

Comment: the answer has been posed but your original didn't work as you used `\string whatever` where `\string` makes (just) the `w` a catcode 12 punctuation character so not equal to the letter `w`, and then you have a spurious `{...}` around the `\newcommand\result` so that whichever branch is taken `\result` is defined but not visible after the test.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code doesn't work because you're using wrong syntax for `\ifthenelse`.

Please check the syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\thing}{whatever}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thing}{\string whatever}}
  {% True case
   \newcommand{\result}{thing is `whatever'.}%
  }
  {% false case
   \newcommand{\result}{thing is something else.}%
  }

\begin{document}

\result

\end{document}
```

This will print

> this is something else.

because `\string` will make the `w` in the second argument different from the `w` in the (expansion of the) first argument to `\equal`.

Removing `\string` will give the expected result

> This is ‘whatever’.

---

You seem to be using

```
\ifthenelse{<test>}{{<code for true>}{<code for false>}}
```

but this is not the right way:

```
\ifthenelse{<test>}{<code for true>}{<code for false>}
```

is the correct syntax.

In your code the `<code for false>` was `\par` (because you missed the third argument to `\ifthenelse`, so TeX picks up the `\par` generated by the blank line). Since the test returns false, nothing is defined.

On the other hand, if you remove `\string` so the test returns true, you'd end up with `\result` being undefined, because you'd execute *two* `\newcommand` instructions, but both inside a group.

---

For a more general approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstringsequalTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringcase}{mO{}m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { #1 } { #3 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\thing}{whatever}
\newcommand{\xyz}{xyz}
\newcommand{\noneoftheabove}{}

\ifstringsequalTF{\thing}{whatever}
  {\newcommand{\result}{thing is `whatever'.}}
  {\newcommand{\result}{thing is something else.}}

\begin{document}

\result

\stringcase{\thing}[OOPS]{
  {whatever}{found whatever}
  {xyz}{found xyz}
}

\stringcase{\xyz}[OOPS]{
  {whatever}{found whatever}
  {xyz}{found xyz}
}

\stringcase{\noneoftheabove}[OOPS]{
  {whatever}{found whatever}
  {xyz}{found xyz}
}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\stringcase` can be omitted and in case of no match nothing would happen.

[image]

Comment: My stupid error! Is the question worth deleting, given that?

Comment: @murray Why delete? You got other possibilities and explanations.

Comment: I guess I've become accustomed to the severe standards of mathematica.stackexchange.com, where a question resulting from a simple syntactical error gets downvoted, quickly closed, and sometimes deleted.

Comment: @murray That's a very different planet. Here you even got four *upvotes*!

Comment: Yes, I have! (I've been much more active on mathematica.stackexchange.com, simply because I know so much more about Mathematica than about TeX/LaTeX.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \def\thing{whatever}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thing}{whatever}}
{\newcommand{\result}{thing is `whatever'.}}
{\newcommand{\result}{thing is something else.}}

\begin{document}

\result

\end{document}
```

Output:

thing is `whatever'.

Comment: I would suggest to use numbers instead and check with `\ifnum\else\fi`