# How can I reduce the "Underfull \vbox badness" warning if I have a tcolorbox box that almost takes up an entire page?

Tags: spacing, errors, tcolorbox, warnings, badness

I want to create a box using the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) package that almost takes up an entire page and here's my MWE of a document that I compiled using LuaLaTeX in a `scrbook` class.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[%
% draft,
twoside,
headings=openany, % parts/chapters start on any page whether it's odd or even
DIV=15, % division factor
BCOR=12.5mm, % binding correction
headsepline=1.5pt, % header line
footsepline=0.4pt, % footer line
numbers=noenddot, % no dots at the end of section numbering
]{scrbook} % 11pt, a4paper (default)
% ----------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
\usepackage[
automark,
% footheight=18pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage} % KOMA-script package for headers, footers, pagestyles
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{} % For spacing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype} % Microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum, blindtext} % For lorem ipsum dummy texts
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % Math packages
\usepackage{physics} % Physics package
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} % Colored boxes
\usepackage{empheq} % Emphasize equations
\usepackage{xcolor} % For colors
\usepackage{xparse} % For document-level commands
\usepackage{xpatch} % For patching commands
\usepackage{etoolbox} % e-TeX toolbox for classes and packages
\usepackage[
hidelinks
]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks and references
\usepackage[capitalise, nameinlink]{cleveref} % Clever cross-referencing features
\usepackage{showframe} % For page layout diagrams
% ----------------------------------------------------
% LAYOUT
  % Headers and footers
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter.\enskip} % Add period after chapter number in header
\automark[section]{chapter} % LE and RO headers
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\ifoot*{} % inner footer
\cfoot*{\pagemark} % central footer
\ofoot*{} % outer footer
  % Part and chapter pagestyles
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}
  % Section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}
  % Section headings
% Font sizes
\setkomafont{part}{\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge}
\setkomafont{section}{\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large}
% Replace \autodot by a fixed dot for chapter headings
\xpretocmd\chapterformat
  {\def\autodot{.}}
  {}{\cfPatchFailed}
% Spacing
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{subsection}
% ----------------------------------------------------
% MACROS
  % Disable the error from using \label with amsmath nested environments
\makeatletter
\def\label@in@display{\gdef\df@label}
\makeatother
  % \ifstringsequalTF and \stringcase
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifstringsequalTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringcase}{mO{}m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { #1 } { #3 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
  % Positive space 
\newcommand{\PositiveSpace}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PS}{r()}
{%
\renewcommand{\PositiveSpace}{#1}
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{0.5}%
  {\quad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{1}%
  {\qquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{1.5}%
  {\qquad\quad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{2}%
  {\qquad\qquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{2.5}%
  {\qquad\qquad\quad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{3}%
  {\qquad\qquad\qquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{3.5}%
  {\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{4}%
  {\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{4.5}%
  {\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\PositiveSpace}{5}%
  {\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}{}%
}
  % Negative space 
\newcommand{\minusquad}{\mkern-18mu}
\newcommand{\minusqquad}{\mkern-36mu}
\newcommand{\NegativeSpace}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\NS}{r()}
{%
\renewcommand{\NegativeSpace}{#1}
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{0.5}%
  {\minusquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{1}%
  {\minusqquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{1.5}%
  {\minusqquad\minusquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{2}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{2.5}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{3}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{3.5}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{4}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{4.5}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusquad}{}%
\ifstringsequalTF{\NegativeSpace}{5}%
  {\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad\minusqquad}{}%
}
  % Resizeable \bullet symbol
\newcommand{\rbullet}[1][.75]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
  % amsthm theorem environments
\newtheoremstyle{dotlessplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\(\rbullet\) \bfseries} % HEADFONT
  { }         % HEADPUNCT
  {\newline} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\theoremstyle{dotlessplain} % italic
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
    % tcolorbox environments
\newtcolorbox{summary}[2][]{colback=black!5!white,
colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,arc=2mm,toptitle=3mm,bottomtitle=3mm,center title,title=\textbf{\Large% 
Summary #2},#1}
% ----------------------------------------------------
% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
% Page 1
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum[1-5][1-79]
\pagebreak
% Page 2
\begin{summary}[boxsep=0pt,left=10pt,right=10pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt]{of Chapter 1}
\(\rbullet\) \textbf{Properties of Addition and Multiplication}
\begin{align*}
    &\text{(Associative law for addition)} \PS(0.5) & a + (b + c) &= (a + b) + c. \tag{P1}  \\
    &\text{(Existence of an additive identity)} \PS(0.5) & a + 0 &= 0 + a = a. \tag{P2} \\
    &\text{(Existence of additive inverses)} \PS(0.5) & a + (-a) &= (-a) + a = 0. \tag{P3} \\
    &\text{(Commutative law for addition)} \PS(0.5) & a + b &= b + a. \tag{P4} \\
    &\text{(Associative law for multiplication)} \PS(0.5) & a \cdot (b \cdot c) &= (a \cdot b) \cdot c. \tag{P5} \\
    &\text{(Existence of a multiplicative identity)} \PS(0.5) & a \cdot 1 &= 1 \cdot a = a;\quad 1 \neq 0. \tag{P6} \\
    &\text{(Existence of multplicative inverses)} \PS(0.5) & a \cdot a^{-1} &= a^{-1} \cdot a = 1, \text{ for } a \neq 0.  \tag{P7} \\
    &\text{(Commutative law for multiplication)} \PS(0.5) & a \cdot b &= b \cdot a. \tag{P8} \\
    &\text{(Distributive law)} \PS(0.5) & a \cdot (b + c) &= a \cdot b + a \cdot c. \tag{P9}
\end{align*}
\vskip 2ex
\(\rbullet\) \textbf{Properties of Inequality and Closure}
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{flalign*}
        &\text{(Trichotomy law) }  \text{For every number } a, \text{one and only one of the following holds:} & \tag{P10}
    \end{flalign*}
    \\
    \begin{align*}
        &\text{(i) } a = 0, && \\
        &\text{(ii) } a \text{ is in the collection } P, && \\
        &\text{(iii) } -a \text{ is in the collection } P. &&
    \end{align*}
    \\[7pt]
    \begin{flalign*}
        &\text{(Closure under addition) If } a \text{ and } b \text{ are in } P, \text{then } a + b \text{ is in } P. & \tag{P11} \\[5pt]
        &\text{(Closure under multiplication) If } a \text{ and } b \text{ are in } P, \text{then } a \cdot b \text{ is in } P. & \tag{P12}
    \end{flalign*}
\end{gather*}
\vskip -3ex
\begin{align*}
    &\PS(0.5) a > b \PS(0.5)\text{ if }\PS(0.5)  a - b \text{ is in } P; \\
    &\PS(0.5) a < b \PS(0.5)\text{ if }\PS(0.5) b > a; \\
    &\PS(0.5) a \geq b \PS(0.5)\text{ if }\PS(0.5) a > b \text{ or } a = b; \\
    &\PS(0.5) a \leq b \PS(0.5)\text{ if }\PS(0.5) a < b \text{ or } a = b.
\end{align*}
\vskip 2ex
\(\rbullet\) \textbf{Definition of the Absolute Value}
\begin{equation*}
\abs{a} = \sqrt{a^2} =
    \begin{cases*}
        \phantom{-}a, & if \(a\geq 0\) \\
        -a, & if \(a\leq 0\).
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}
\vskip 3ex
\begin{theorem}[\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality}{The Triangle Inequality}] 
        For all numbers \(a\) and \(b\), we have
        \[\abs{a + b} \leq \abs{a} + \abs{b}.\]
    \end{theorem}
\end{summary}
\vspace{\fill}
\pagebreak
% Page 3
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\lipsum[1-5][1-79]
\end{document}
```

The result to my untrained eye seems to be just fine

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]

but what I don't understand is why LaTeX tells me there's an `Underfull \vbox (badness ...)`warning.

[image: Warning]

So again, my question is how can I reduce the badness to remove the warning for this case specifically?

I've been looking everywhere for solutions on how to reduce/remove the `Underfull \vbox (badness ...)` warnings given by LaTeX and some solutions suggest that I could simply suppress the warnings if I wanted to but I'm afraid it might affect the typography of the whole document so I've avoided doing that so far. Thank you.

Comment: It's only a warning, you can ignore it or add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble (with `\raggedbottom` you avoid additional space among paragraphs to fill the page.

Comment: It seems to fix it. Are there any side effects to adding `\raggedbottom`? Also, if you don't mind could you please create an answer so I can accept it? Thanks! :D

Comment: The side effect is that it does not fill the pages between the paragraphs but at the end. See my answer.

Comment: not directly related to the question but the definitions of `PositiveSpace` and friends seem weirdly complicated. As far as I can tell you just want `\newcommand{\PositiveSpace}[1]{\hspace{2\dimexpr1em\relax}}`

Comment: Why don't you use \newpage instead of \pagebreak?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in my document I often find myself using `\qquad` (and the negative space equivalent) a lot and so I wanted to create two shorthand macros `\PS` (Positive Space) and `\NS` (Negative Space) that each take an input in units of `\qquad`s  (or `\minusqquad`s). I'm not very good or  experienced in using the [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse?lang=en) package and I also don't understand  `expl` syntax so I simply made up my unnecessarily complicated macro for horizontal spacing inspired by [egreg's answer to conditionals with strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451094/228055)

Comment: If you'd like to help me, I'm willing to ask another question on how to properly define such macros, if you don't mind, of course. Thank you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh this solution seems to also work. Thanks! I suppose there is no difference in using `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` *if* the page is `raggedbottom` (though I may be mistaken). So the solution seems to be either I simply use `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak` or I simply add `\raggedbottom` to the preamble ([or toggle it locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226716/scoping-raggedbottom-to-a-single-page))

Comment: No, but if you want a short page then using \pagebreak isn't the right command as its goal is to stretch the page (if flushbottom is active).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you.

Comment: \quad is just `\hspace{1em}`  so `\quad\quad\quad` is just a slow way of doing `\hspace{3em}`  so there is never a need to do that (and such explicit space commands should usually be avoided in any case, you should almost never need such space commands in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add `\raggedbottom` that avoids additional space among paragraphs to fill the page.

I'll show you the difference between using it or not using it in the following examples. To simplify, I don't use your MWE, but it's just to explain the concept.

This example does NOT use `\raggedbottom`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is what happens \emph{without} \textbackslash \texttt{raggedbottom}}
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My first box, colframe=red]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My second box, colframe=green]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

This is the same example WITH `\raggedbottom`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is what happens \emph{with} \textbackslash \texttt{raggedbottom}}
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
Some text before the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My first box, colframe=red]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
Some text after the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My second box, colframe=green]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Choosing one or another is a matter of taste or depends on the typographic conventions you must follow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using your solution but since I want most of my document to be `flushbottom` I simply used [`\oneraggedpage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226716/228055) to toggle `raggedbottom` locally whenever needed. Again, thanks and have a nice day! :)

Comment: @FarrelAhmed You're welcome!